# Register custom Doctrine DBAL types in Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel, doctrine-orm, dbal

Just recently I on-boarded a Laravel 5 project and faced the problem of extending Doctrine DBAL implementation with custom types supported by Postgres.
I have to plug in nicely https://github.com/opensoft/doctrine-postgres-types and https://github.com/boldtrn/JsonbBundle into the application configuration. Coming from Symfony2 I was expecting that there will be a smooth way of adding it to Doctrine's configuration (as in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types-in-the-schematool). Sadly it doesn't seem to be the case.

I saw the suggestion mentioned in 2013 by *betawax* in https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1675, also replied by *tylorotwell* that there are no plans for such kind of support. I don't feel convinced this is the right way to do it.

Did anyone overcome this obstacle recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some further research I've created my own package with support of some additional functions and datatypes for PostgreSql 9.4 on Laravel and Symfony. 
Below is a working solution for my initial question (see original instructions [here](https://www.packagist.org/packages/martin-georgiev/postgresql-for-doctrine)):

The steps below are based on Laravel 5 integration with FoxxMD's fork of mitchellvanw/laravel-doctrine.

1) Register the functions and datatype mappings:

```
# Usually part of config/doctrine.php
<?php

return [
    'entity_managers' => [
        'name_of_your_entity_manager' => [
            'dql' => [
                'string_functions' => [
                    // Array data types related functions
                    'ALL' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\All',
                    'ANY' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Any',
                    'ARRAY' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Arr',
                    'ARRAY_APPEND' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ArrayAppend',
                    'ARE_OVERLAPING_EACH_OTHER' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ArrayAreOverlapingEachOther',
                    'ARRAY_CARDINALITY' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ArrayCardinality',
                    'ARRAY_CAT' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ArrayCat',
                    'ARRAY_PREPEND' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ArrayPrepend',
                    'ARRAY_REMOVE' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ArrayRemove',
                    'ARRAY_REPLACE' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ArrayReplace',
                    'ARRAY_TO_STRING' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ArrayToString',
                    'STRING_TO_ARRAY' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\StringToArray',

                    // Functions and operators used by both array and json(-b) data types
                    'CONTAINS' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Contains',
                    'IS_CONTAINED_BY' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\IsContainedBy',

                    // Json(-b) data type related functions and operators
                    'JSON_GET_FIELD' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonGetField',
                    'JSON_GET_FIELD_AS_TEXT' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonGetFieldAsText',
                    'JSON_GET_OBJECT' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonGetObject',
                    'JSON_GET_OBJECT_AS_TEXT' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonGetObjectAsText',
                    'JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonbArrayElements',
                    'JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonbArrayElementsText',
                    'JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonbArrayLength',
                    'JSONB_EACH' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonbEach',
                    'JSONB_EACH_TEXT' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonbEachText',
                    'JSONB_EXISTS' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonbObjectKeys',
                    'JSONB_OBJECT_KEYS' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonbExists',

                    // Basic text search related functions and operators
                    'TO_TSQUERY' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ToTsquery',
                    'TO_TSVECTOR' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ToTsvector',
                    'TSMATCH' => 'MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Tsmatch',
                ],
            ],
            'mapping_types' => [
                'jsonb' => 'jsonb',
                '_jsonb' => 'jsonb[]',
                'jsonb[]' => 'jsonb[]',
            ],
```

2) Add EventSubscriber for Doctrine

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Handlers\Events;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber as Subscriber;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Event\ConnectionEventArgs;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Events;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class DoctrineEventSubscriber implements Subscriber
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::postConnect,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionEventArgs $args
     * @throws DBALException
     */
    public function postConnect(ConnectionEventArgs $args)
    {
        Type::addType('jsonb', "\MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Jsonb");
        Type::addType('jsonb[]', "\MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\JsonbArray");
    }
}
```

3) Add the EventSubscriber for Doctrine to a ServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Providers;

use Config;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry as DoctrineManagerRegistry;
use Acme\Handlers\Events\DoctrineEventSubscriber;

/**
 * Class EventServiceProvider
 * @package Quantum\Providers
 */
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register Doctrine Events as well.
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerDoctrineEvents();
        $this->registerDoctrineTypeMapping();
    }

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     * @param DispatcherContract $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);
    }

    /**
     * Register Doctrine events.
     */
    private function registerDoctrineEvents()
    {
        $eventManager = $this->registry()->getConnection()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->addEventSubscriber(new DoctrineEventSubscriber);
    }

    /**
     * Register any custom Doctrine type mappings
     */
    private function registerDoctrineTypeMapping()
    {
        $databasePlatform = $this->registry()->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
        $entityManagers = Config::get('doctrine.entity_managers');
        foreach ($entityManagers as $entityManager) {
            if (array_key_exists('mapping_types', $entityManager)) {
                foreach ($entityManager['mapping_types'] as $dbType => $doctrineName) {
                    $databasePlatform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping($dbType, $doctrineName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the entity manager registry
     * @return DoctrineManagerRegistry
     */
    function registry()
    {
        return app(DoctrineManagerRegistry::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to just register one DBAL type, you can do it like this:

1. Create new type

   ```php
   use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType;

   class CitextType extends StringType
   {
       public function getName(): string
       {
           return 'citext';
       }
   }
   ```
2. Map database type with class via `database.php` config:

   ```php
   'dbal' => [
     'types' => [
       'citext' => CitextType::class,
     ],
   ],
   ```

   Or via `DB::registerDoctrineType(CitextType::class, 'citext', 'citext')` somewhere in service providers
3. If you use `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`, add next to the `ide-helper.php` config

   ```php
   'custom_db_types' => [
       'postgresql' => [
           'citext' => 'string',
       ],
   ],
   ```